# How to check if the object is assigned to another object | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a django case like below:
**models.py**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Room No.",max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Room"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name",max_length=200)
    father_name = models.CharField("father Name",max_length=200)
    cell_no = models.CharField("cell No",max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField("address",max_length=500)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='all_rooms')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Student"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def room(request):
    allrooms= Room.objects.all()

    form = RoomForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Room added successfully.")
        return redirect('/room')
    context = {'allrooms':allrooms, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'room.html', context)
```

In **templates** in room.html I want to show the status Vacant/Occupied based on the fact if a room is assigned to some student or not. I have the following code in template but it shows 'Vacant' status for all rooms.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Room</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     {% for room in allrooms %}
                     <tr>
                        <td>{{ room.name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                           {% if room.student_set.all %}
                           <small class="badge badge-danger">Occupied</small>
                           {% elif not room.student.all %}
                           <small class="badge badge-success">Vacant</small>
                           {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'updateroom' room.id %}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                     </tr>
                     {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
               </table>
```

Please help someone to show he status of the room.

Answer (score 0):

to get assigned and unassigned rooms you have to write queries with respect to the related field(in this case the foreign key "all_rooms") as follows:

```
total_rooms = Room.objects.all().annotate(num_rooms=Count("all_rooms"))
assigned_rooms = total_rooms.filter(num_rooms__gt=0)
unassigned_rooms = total_rooms.exclude(num_rooms__gt=0)
```

On running, these queries will return the room instances:
[image: room instances output]